# Alarm Manager and BroadCastReceiver not firing

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

The following code I have in `onCreate` for one of my `Activity` classes. I am expecting a log output every second when I enter that activity, but nothing happens.

```
private void setupAlarm() {

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AdhIntent.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            0, intent, 0);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000, pendingIntent);
}


private class AdhIntent extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public AdhIntent() {
        System.out.println("2014");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("2014");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `AdhIntent` needs to be a `public` class. Otherwise, Android cannot create an instance of it.

Second, `AdhIntent` needs to be registered in the manifest in a `<receiver>` element. Otherwise, Android cannot send a broadcast to it via your `PendingIntent`.

You also do not need `getApplicationContext()` -- only use that when you know **completely and precisely why** you are using it.

Finally, using `AlarmManager` to get control every second is not a particularly good use of `AlarmManager`. At best, that's fine for book examples, or for lightweight testing. If you really need to get control somewhere every second, there are better solutions, assuming that getting control every second is actually a sensible choice.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't clear from the docs that the class should be public. The registration in the manifest was a bit different from what it says in the documentation. Regarding getApplicationContext(), should I change it to getApplication()?

Comment: @hajder: Just delete it outright and just call `getSystemService()`.

Comment: which should I pass in as a parameter? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String)

Comment: @hajder: `ALARM_SERVICE`, as you have it now.